# How can I install PHP 5.4 in Debian 7.5 (Wheezy)?

Tags: debian, php, debian-wheezy, php5

I wonder if you have any way to install PHP 5.4 on Debian 7.5 via `apt-get`, adding some URL in `sources.list`.

I added the following lines however it asks a lot of dependencies:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org/ squeeze-php54 all
deb-src squeeze-php54 all http://packages.dotdeb.org
```

Comment: Why on Earth are you trying to install PHP in Debian using some unknown third-party site? Sorry but did you even bother first searching for "php" on [the Debian package archive site](http://packages.debian.org)? Or, basically, doing `apt-cache search php` -- as suggested in any Debian handbook?

Comment: Note that your strange site uses "squeeze-php54" as the release name, suggesting that those packages are really built for Squeeze -- a Debian release preceding Wheezy, the current stable one.  Hence it looks like you've just blindly followed some outdated blog post/HOWTO. That's a really bad practice! You should try to make sence of any command or configuration file snippet a guide wants you to run/apply. Otherwise you can easily wreak havoc on your system.

Comment: I am using this way because that's how I met for the installation of PHP 5.4. I am also using this machine the paravirtualizar vagrant and the puppet to set up.

As the dependencies thought the apt-get solve the dependencies alone. If not mistaken YUM solve such dependence. I am new to the debian world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5.4 is the default version in Debian wheezy.

> https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/php5

You should be able to install it using

```
apt-get install php5
```

if you have the normal wheezy repositories in your `sources.list`

Those lines you added in your `sources.list` seems to be for Debian squeeze, which was the release *before* wheezy.

So if you do have problems, you should really check that your `sources.list` contains the wheezy repositories.